# How to choose ingress controller in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, k3s

### Context

I have a **k3s** (v1.19.3+k3s3) cluster and I am using the '*out of the box*' [traefik ingress controler](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/networking/)

```sh
kubectl  get svc -n kube-system 
NAME                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
kube-dns             ClusterIP      10.43.0.10      <none>          53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       5d16h
metrics-server       ClusterIP      10.43.127.152   <none>          443/TCP                      5d16h
traefik-prometheus   ClusterIP      10.43.73.131    <none>          9100/TCP                     5d16h
traefik              LoadBalancer   10.43.121.125   111.11.11.111   80:32492/TCP,443:31586/TCP   5d16h
```

```sh
kubectl   -n kube-system describe svc traefik
Name:                     traefik
Namespace:                kube-system
Labels:                   app=traefik
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          chart=traefik-1.81.0
                          heritage=Helm
                          release=traefik
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: traefik
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: kube-system
Selector:                 app=traefik,release=traefik
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.43.121.125
LoadBalancer Ingress:     111.11.11.111
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32492/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.0.6:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31586/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.0.6:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

### The issue

I do not find how to use this ingress controller using a helm chart (say, this [ghost chart](https://github.com/groundhog2k/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/ghost)). In my  understanding of how Helm charts work and the purpose they fulfill, `Ingress` templating allow to use different ingress controllers. Here is the chart's `ingress.yaml`

```yaml
...
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "ghost.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: {{ $maxSize }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
...
```

Based on this, I would say that I need to edit the `annotations` section of `values.yaml` to **use traefik** instead of default `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`

```yaml
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik  # what should I use?
  hosts:
    - host: some.domain.io
      paths:
        - /
  tls:
    - secretName: chart-example-tls
      hosts:
        - some.domain.io
```

However, no matter what I try in `annotations`, `helm install` keep getting

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to create resource: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1beta1/ingresses?timeout=10s": service "ingress-nginx-controller-admission" not found
```

as if helm were looking for an **Nginx ingress controler**, no matter what. Is this a possible limitation of charts (like this one) or am I misconceiving how Helm charts work? How can I use the default `traefik ingress` on this chart's deployment?

Answer (score 1):

No, as per I know - you are not able to chose exact ingress controller for these chart. Both Nginx and Traefik use same ports, so you have to define proper ingress controller in advance.

From [chart documentation](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/ghost) i see that :

> This chart has been tested to work with NGINX Ingress, cert-manager,
> bla bla

And the helm options you have are:
[image]

From all the above written I have a question|proposition: Dont you want to [switch to NGINX ingress controller in K3s](https://dev.to/sr229/how-to-use-nginx-ingress-controller-in-k3s-2ck2)?

**Getting your cluster ready**
First order of business is that you need to get your cluster have no other ingress controllers as this would conflict with your current ingress controllers. This is because ****NGINX and Traefik both listens to 80 and 443**, **which causes conflicts** **with each other**, so make sure your K3s cluster only has one kind of the other.**

For the best results, your K3s cluster must be installed with the `--no-deploy-traefik` argument, which will cause the K3s cluster to deploy only with the bare container orchestrator without the default HTTP backend, which is Traefik.

To make sure you don't have a Traefik controller installed, run `kubectl get deployments -n kube-system` to see if Traefik is gone.

If you have verified Traefik is not there, then you may proceed with the next part.

**Installing NGINX**
There's two ways to install NGINX, either from a Helm chart or a direct kubectl apply -f

**Using a Helm chart**
The NGINX ingress is available in the Helm Stable Charts, and if you have the stable registry already installed in your Helm CLI, simply run helm install stable/nginx-ingress.

You may also modify the installation using the following configurations stated here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Vitalii. Actually, I am switching to **Nginx** right now (no question about this being easier). My question was more an academic one (*is it possible?*, *do typical charts allow these implementation differences?* *should they?* and *how could they?*)

Answer (score 1):

You were correct in your thinking, e.g. in a Helm chart you should be able to define by annotations the ingress correctly.

For example https://github.com/stefanprodan/podinfo/blob/master/charts/podinfo/templates/ingress.yaml

which defines annotations like:

```
{{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ toYaml . | indent 4 }}
```

you could apply traefik specific annotations like

```
  annotations:
        traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
        traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls.certresolver: myresolver
        traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: kube-system-traefik-forward-auth@kubernetescrd
```

In the chart from your question:
https://github.com/groundhog2k/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/ghost/templates/ingress.yaml#L16

the annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size
```

is hardcoded. That shouldn't stop the deployment to work properly.
You are stating that it looks as Helm is "looking" for Nginx ingress controller which is not true, afaik. Helm is not looking for anything.
Also apart from that specific reference in annotations, i can't find anything nginx hardcoded, values are commented out.
https://github.com/groundhog2k/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/ghost/values.yaml#L60
So the correct answer is that you still had a faulty nginx ingress deployment.